# Trigger click event on specific item in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf

I've a `ListView`, each item of the list have associated an event with: `MouseLeftButtonDown`, this event called a method that will display some details of the item clicked.

Now what I'm trying to achieve is trigger this event by selecting the item behind code. Suppose that in listview I've this item:

```
Foo
Foo2
```

I've `Foo2` stored in an object variable. What I did:

```
object currentItem = "Foo2";
MyList.SelectedItem = currentItem;
```

the problem's that isn't possible fire the `MouseLeftButtonDown` by selecting an item behind code.
What I need is fire `MouseLeftButtonDown` on the `ListViewItem` contained inside the variable `currentItem`, that of course, is available also in the list `MyList`.

Is possible do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the selected item contain all the information you want to display? If so, you could simply bind the elements displaying additional information directly to properties of the ListBox.SelectedItem. If you don't want the elements to display until there is an item selected, bind the visibility of the panel containing the elements to the ListBox's SelectedItem property with a NullToVisibilityConverter (mentioned several times on StackOverflow).

This way you have a completely declarative view on your UI, drastically reducing the complexity of the code behind.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use **listView_SelectionChanged** event to manuplate your data.